# Is there any version of Angular Material md-select with select all option

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular-material, multipleselection

I have been using Angular Material in one of my project. Suddenly I realized the need for having a select all option on md-select. I think I will pull a git request for the same.

However, currently I am looking for a similar drop down structure with checkboxes (like md-select multiple) but also a select all option.

**I am aware that I can push a dummy empty entry into md-select option array and manipulate reverse way on its selection. But it would require a lot of code change in my current structure and would also not be a elegant thing to do.**

I tried looking for it in bootstrap and jQuery-UI, but could not find one yet. Is there any such control known to anyone. Any redirection will be helpful.

Comment: I guess you need use md-chips with autocomplete instead. A multi-select dont look right in material design, besides probably in touch screens would be awful to use.

Comment: @Velasquez: I doubt if you got me correct. I am looking for something which can select all values from dropdown in one click or one touch. For instance, in Gmail we can click a top checkbox which selects all mails on that page

Comment: Ok, i got you. Maybe you can add an <md-item ng-click="selectAll()">Select All</md-item> before the <md-item ng-repeat ... >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily inside the HTML. It requires only one line of code, or two lines, if you want a "select none" option as well. For example

```
<md-input-container>
  <label>Users</label>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedUser" multiple="" 
               ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
      <md-optgroup label="Users">
      <md-option ng-repeat="user in users" 
                 ng-value="user">{{ user.name }}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
<button ng-click="selectedUser=users">all</button>
<button ng-click="selectedUser=[]">none</button>
```

[Example in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5bJk7QLqvSCPQsgqjrBM?p=preview).

Edit: I updated the below Plunker to show the "all" button inside the select box next to the "Users" optgroup title. The relevant change:

```
    <md-select ng-model="selectedUser" multiple="" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
      <button ng-click="doSelectedUser()" style="float:right">all</button>
      <md-optgroup label="Users">
```

Comment: @ C14L : Ofcourse, this can be done; but this is not what I am looking for..What I want is the button you have provided (or checkbox) to be within the drop down menu (probably besides your Users label). Angular material builds the drop down on the fly, hence I am unable to achieve it

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari I updated the Plunker. You can simply put the button insude the `md-select` above the optgroup title and `float:right` it.

Comment: I made few changes to your plunker. hope you would like to view them:

`<md-input-container>
     <label>Users</label>
       <md-select ng-model="selectedUser" multiple="" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
          <md-checkbox ng-click="doSelectedUser()" style="float:left"></md-checkbox>
          <md-optgroup label="[SelectAll]">
            <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }}</md-option>
          </md-optgroup>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>`

Comment: And also this in script

 `$scope.doSelectedUser = function () {
      if($scope.selectedUser.length > 0)
      $scope.selectedUser = [];
      else 
      $scope.selectedUser = $scope.users;
    }`

Comment: This makes it more of what I was originally looking for. Thanks for providing the right direction. I hope with little modification, this should serve the purpose. Also I would appreciate, if you could modify your plunker with above changes, just in case for other users.